# Show message when product in cart is out of stock

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop-1.7

Lately I've updated to prestashop-1.7.5 and the problem is that when one or more products is out of stock , customer cannot proceed and the cart page just keep refreshing on "Order button click".
How can I show error message in cart page when a product is out of stock ?

Comment: Your other error messages work ?

Comment: @Fizik26 yeap , I guess in this case there is no error message hook in the cart page!!

Comment: Are you sure that all plugins that you are using are compatible with your Prestashop version ? Sometimes you can have this error because of a plugin.

Comment: Do you have this box ? Preferences --> Product -->  Allow ordering of out-of-stock products

Comment: @fizik26 I am not using any plugins, only prestashop shopping cart itself .

Comment: @Fizik26 And yes, I have that box! and it's disabled

Comment: You can use this module if you want to use it -> https://addons.prestashop.com/fr/emails-notifications/20091-out-of-stock-notification.html . I have download a version of Prestashop, update to 1.7.5 and I don't have any problem with this ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must have an incompatibility with your theme, because the prestashop default theme prevents you from ordering and indicates an error.

Regards,

Comment: thanks, I'm kind of agree with you. you got any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: It should activate the errors, you should have the info